# Getting info from NSData object

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsstring, nsdata

How would I get `returningResponse` (into say, a NSString) from the following code:

```
NSURLResponse* response;
NSError* error;
NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

I think I can get the info that I need into a string but I can't call anything on `response` because it's null. Therefore, I assume that I need to call something on `result`. The problem is, I don't know what to call.

(The URL request has been coded prior to the code sample. I know that that works.) I want to be able to detect if the request as successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation for the URL loading system](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html):

> If NSURLConnection is unable to download the URL the method will return nil and any available NSError instance by-reference in the appropriate parameter.

So, see what's in your "error" parameter to find out what the problem is.

Comment: @David - How so? Code please? (Yes, I'm being lazy, but isn't that natural to being a programmer?)

Comment: See the NSError class reference. Or, on the simplest level, just NSLog it:
     NSLog(@"%@", error);

Comment: Thanks. Silly me, I didnt realize that the error value was being passed by (erm, reference, or value? I'm not very good with those terms... )

Comment: "by reference" it is. That's what the "&" means.